# FCM integration in Android app which uses Android.Mk build

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to integrate the FCM in Android application which uses Android.mk build system in framework build

Is there any alternative to use "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" in Andorid.mk or  Android.bp other build system?

Comment: @Satish, were you able to integrate Firebase support for apps built along with AOSP? Did you figure out how to get all the dependencies for Firebase (the aar and jar)?

Answer (score -1):

What the plugin does essentially is parse your `google-services.json` file and copies the values in it into an xml resource file. It then injects some code into your project that takes care of calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp` for you.

You can of course do all this yourself if you want to.

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
  android:authorities="yourapp.package.name.myFcmInitProvider"
  android:name=".MyFcmInitProvider"
  android:exported="false" />
<!-- Make sure that Google's FirebaseInitProvider isn't included in your app -->
<provider
  android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
  android:authorities="yourapp.package.name.firebaseinitprovider"
  android:exported="false"
  tools:node="remove" />
```

MyFcmInitProvider.kt:

```
class MyFcmInitProvider : ContentProvider() {
    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        // Application ID can be found in google-services.json.
        // Add additional credentials as necessary.
        val builder = FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApplicationId(myApplicationId)
        if (null == FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, builder.build())) {
            // Initialization failed
        }
        return false
    }   

    // Required overrides
    override fun getType(uri: Uri?): String? = null
    override fun delete(uri: Uri?, selection: String? selectionArgs: Array<out String>?): Int = 0
    override fun update(uri: Uri?, values: ContentValues?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?): Int = 0
    override fun insert(uri: Uri?, values: ContentValues?): Uri? = null
    override fun query(uri: Uri?, projection: Array<out String>?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?, sortOrder: String?): Cursor? = null
}
```